# Give an equation for a line that contains no lattice points.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Give an equation for a line that contains no lattice points. Explain how you know it contains no lattice points.

This problem is taken from section 5.1 exercise Q.9. of book: Number theory, by: James Pommersheim.
The chapter is titled: Linear diophantine equations.

The hint given is: Use a proof by contradiction. Follow the proof of Theorem 5.1.1.

The theorem 5.1.1 states: Let $a, b$ be integers. If $\gcd(a,b)>1$, then the equation $aX + bY =1$ has no integral solutions.

It continues by having $d = \gcd(a,b)$. Then assumes there exist $X, Y \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $aX + bY =1$.

Now, as $d \mid a, b$, so by Linear combination lemma have:
$d \mid aX + bY$.

So, it follows that $d\mid 1$. Thus, $d=1$, which contradicts the hypothesis.

Hence, concludes there are no integers $X, Y$ s.t. $aX + bY= 1$.

How to take a proof by contradiction by following above proof is unclear. The reason is cannot have $d$ as a fraction, which is the only option left, if consider non-lattice points; as it is $=\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Your statement "If $\gcd(a,b)>1$, then the equation $aX+bY=1$." is incomplete.  Presumably you meant to finish it as "then the equation $aX+bY=1$ has no integer solutions", which is clearly true (as it would imply that $1$ was divisible by $\gcd(a,b)$).

Comment: I don't know what a fractional gcd is.  If $d>1$ divides both $a$ and $b$ then of course $d$ divides any combination of the form $aX+bY$ where $X, Y$ are integers.  For an explicit  example, $2X+2Y=1$ has no integer solutions since $2X+2Y$ is even whenever $X,Y$ are integers.

Comment: There is nothing called "fractional gcd".  I can't understand why you are stuck.  Clearly $d=\gcd(a,b)$ divides every integer of the form $aX+bY$ for $X, Y\in \mathbb Z$.  Indeed, if $a=dA$ and $b=dB$ then $aX+bY=d\times (AX+BY)$.  I don't see where a problem arises.

Comment: @lulu then how to pursue the question using its hint, or even by other approach.

Comment: I don't understand.  I've given you a full solution.  Just think about the line $2X+2Y=1$ if the general case is too hard for you.  Or consider $y=\sqrt 2 \,x +\sqrt 3$, for a different sort of example.

Comment: @lulu your second example presents $ax+b(\sqrt{2}x +\sqrt{3})=1\implies x(a+b\sqrt{2}) =1-b\sqrt{3} \implies x= \frac{ 1-b\sqrt{3} }{(a+b\sqrt{2})}$. What does it tell?

Comment: If $x,y$ are integers then square to get $3=y^2-2\sqrt 2 xy + 4 x^2$. Which would imply that $\sqrt 2 $ was rational which it's not

Comment: @lulu kindly present an answer. Might be it helps even more.